# Factory for series of dependent elements

Tags: .net, factory, factory-pattern

I'm developing a Track Builder (for my future racing game) that's generating tracks. After being built, track is processed by the game engine and so on. Track is a collection of elements, which can be:

- short / long straight
- slow / medium / fast corner

Each element has a length property, which should be generated while building track's element. Elements are dependant on the one which was before during generation (it's a bit strange to have fast corner after slow one).

For the first time I went for the solution of "ifing":

```
public class ElementType
{
    ...
    public double GenerateLength()
    {
        switch (m_TypeEnum)
        {
            case ElementTypeEnum.SlowSpeedCorner:
                return Parameters.SlowCornerAvgLength+Generator.GetDeviation;
            ...
            case ElementTypeEnum.LongStraight:
            default:
                return Parameters.LongStraightAvgLength + Generator.GetDeviation(Parameters.LongStraightLengthMaxDeviation);
        }
    }
    ...
    public IList<ElementType> GetPossibleSuccessors()
    {
        switch (m_TypeEnum)
        {
            case ElementTypeEnum.SlowSpeedCorner:
                return new List<ElementType>() { new ElementType(ElementTypeEnum.SlowSpeedCorner), new ElementType(ElementTypeEnum.ShortStraight), new ElementType(ElementTypeEnum.LongStraight) };
            ...
            case ElementTypeEnum.LongStraight:
            default:
                return new List<ElementType>() { new ElementType(ElementTypeEnum.SlowSpeedCorner), new ElementType(ElementTypeEnum.MediumSpeedCorner), new ElementType(ElementTypeEnum.FastSpeedCorner) };
        }
    }
}

public enum ElementTypeEnum : int
{
    LongStraight = 1,
    SlowSpeedCorner = 2,
}
```

And the generator was basing on method:

```
public static TrackElement GenerateElement(TrackElement Predecessor)
{
    ElementType type = SelectElementType(Predecessor);
    double length = type.GenerateLength();
    return new TrackElement(type, length);
}

private static ElementType SelectElementType(TrackElement Predecessor)
{
    IList<ElementType> successors = Predecessor.Type.GetPossibleSuccessors();
    int possibleSuccessors = successors.Count;
    int selected = Generator.GetInt(possibleSuccessors);
    return successors[selected];
}
```

But as you can guess, this is a drama when consuming it in the engine - too much "ifing" as a result for every property. So I moved elements to different classes basing on:

```
public abstract class TrackElement
{
    public TrackElement(double Length)
    {
        m_length = Length;
    }
    protected abstract static double GenerateLength();

   public sealed double Length 
   { 
        get
        {
            return m_length;
        }
   }
}
```

But now I have problem with building track using provided class:

```
public static TrackElement GenerateElement(TrackElement Predecessor)
{
    ??? type = SelectElementType(Predecessor);
    double length = type.GenerateLength();
    return new ???(length);
}
```

Of course I know that I can't do like this because GenerateLength is static, I wanted only to draft my problem. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the logic of ordering tracks from the logic of construction; move it to the entity responsible for building a complete track.  Then have your factory have useful names.

```
public abstract class TrackElementFactory
{
    public abstract TrackElement CreateFastCurve();
    public abstract TrackElement CreateLongStraight();
}

public class TrackArranger
{
     public Track CreateAwesomeTrack()
     {
          var factory = //get from somewhere
          var track = new Track();
          track.Add(factory.CreateFastCurve());
          track.Add(factory.CreateLongStraight());
          ....
          return track;
     }
}
```

Also, you are likely to be happier with this change to your TrackElement abstraction.  It allows your implementations to be cleaner.

```
public abstract class TrackElement
{
   public abstract double Length 
   { 
        get;
   }
}
```